# mongoose compund unique index does not work

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have following index:

```
PaymentSchema.index({ driver_id: 1, year: 1, month: 1 },{ unique: true });
```

So I want this collection to hold just one record for each different combination of fields `driver_id, year and month`. I want to update collection with `upsert` option:

```
    var query = {
        driver_id: req.params.driver_id,
        year: req.params.year,
        month: req.params.month,
        amount: req.params.old_value
    };

    var update = {
        $set: {
            amount: req.params.new_value
        }
    };

    var options = {
        upsert: true  
    };

    Payment.update(query,update,options,function(err,rows){
        if(err) return next(err);
        res.json({});
    });
```

So what I want is to update document with given unique key (driver_id+year+month) and with additional condition `amount = ...`. If query conditions are ok document should be updated - and it works. If document is not found according to this conditions and document with unique index does not exist it is created. But if document with unique index exists (only amount condition is incorrect) then a new document in created with same unique index (driver_id + year + month). It is strange because I declared unique index on those 3 fields (driver_id+year+month) and I can see in mongoshell that there exist two documents with those fields the same...

Comment: Can you add to your question output from `getIndexes`: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.getIndexes/

Answer (score 0):

Solved: I had to restart `mongod` and delete database (probably reindex option would work too).